# Find a file with crawl id

Tags: crawl, anti-virus

I have a file which were detected by McAfee as trojan during every crawl of my SharePoint 2013 site. (every 15min)

McAfee try to remove it but it does not succeed.

I have the entry about : 
1st time
System:Remote   E:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\a2003b29-4abd-4cfe-b85e-2c6c6600b17e-crawl-0\gthrsvc\6e\0x2b26e.doc\word/embeddings/oleObject1.bin

then:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\bin\mssdmn.exe   E:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Data\Office Server\Applications\gthrsvc\flt10396_7664.doc\word/embeddings/oleObject1.bin

Is it possible to find which is the file ? I see that it's a doc file. 
However I cannot find out where it is what is the name of the file.

Is it possible to find the name of the file with the crawl identifier ? like flt10396_7664.doc

Additional information is : that it firs happened on 9th of December at 2AM.